# Will Alice: Madness Returns run on a 2010 MacBook Pro?

Tags: windows-7, alice-madness-returns

I look forward to buying *Alice: Madness Returns*, but I'm not sure if will run on my 2010 MacBook Pro running Windows 7. Will it run well?

Comment: Do you have the specs for your Macbook?

Comment: Nvidia GT 330M; 
Intel i7 2,8 GHz; 
4 GB Ram

Comment: Questions asking if a game will run on a specific system is off-topic as per [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/can-i-ask-if-a-specific-game-will-run-on-a-specific-computer-system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Macs, so I can't say if Bootcamp / etc makes games not work as well as on a non-Mac, but looking at the hardware, your CPU and RAM are more than sufficient.

The bottleneck in your machine will be the graphics card. According to [Notebookcheck](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-330M.22437.0.html), its roughly equivalent to a Quadro FX 3500M, which I have in a laptop of mine, and is definitely better than a desktop GeForce 7600, which is the minimum requirement of the game.

Basically, provided your drivers are up to date, the game should run, but you'll probably have to lower some settings to keep it smooth and playable.

Comment: For the record, Boot Camp is simply Apple's multi-boot environment. When booting to Windows via Boot Camp, you are rebooting the machine entirely and running Windows only, natively.

Comment: @John Ah ok, I thought that Boot Camp involved some form of BIOS emulation that might affect performance, since Macs use EFI that makes it really hard to get Mac OS running inside a virtual machine >.< guess I was wrong on that one then =]

Answer (score 1):

I found [this link](http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=505&game=American%20McGees%20Alice%202), where an Nvidia GeForce GT320 is quoted as the minimum requirement.

So, in theory, your MacBook Pro should run the game.